# How can I fix Flamingo Device File Explorer's limited file display in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Flamingo Device File Explorer can't show all files，data/ only show 3 folder。

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
1.open device File explorer
2.data/ only show 3 folder
3.use terminal tool show all file

Is there a temporary solution to solve the Android studio problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.